# Trying to set Border of an UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am new to swift and I am trying to set a black border around my `UIImageView` but I am unable to do so. This is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var flagImage: UIImageView!
var image = UIImage(named: "estonia")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    flagImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
    flagImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

    flagImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    flagImage.image = image
 }
```

Could I get some help on this?

Comment: I think u should accept an answer

Answer (score 25):

> You gave the border color to the imageView but how could you expect to see the color with out any area to fill in. So, the

```
flagImage.layer.borderWidth = 2 /** as you wish **/
```

> Gives the Area around the imageView of thickness 2 to fill in the color you gave.

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this

**Objective-C**

```
flagImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

**Swift**

```
flagImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

you only MISS borderWidth = 1 (x)

Answer (score -2):

Made an `ImageView` that was say 65w x 65h. I then dragged another image view over it in interface builder and made it 67wx67h. I then changed its background to black and moved it behind the other. This will give the first `imageView` a black border. Just adjust the black image view as needed to adjust the border thickness.

[image: did a gray border in the image, yours would be black]